Problem Generating .xlsx File from Tilde-Delimiited File
When I try to convert a tilde-delimited file to a .xlsx using the code below, I get this error:

Unable to activate axlsx-2.0.1, because rubyzip-2.3.2 conflicts with rubyzip (~> 1.0.0) ...

# Load the tilde-delimited file
csv = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(fid, extension: :csv, col_sep: '~')

# Create a new Excel workbook
Axlsx::Package.new 
do |p|
    p.workbook.add_worksheet(name: 'Sheet1') 
    do |sheet|
       csv.each_with_index 
       do |row, row_index|
          row.each_with_index 
          do |cell, col_index|
             sheet.add_row([cell])
          end
       end
    end
    p.serialize(fidx)
end

Uninstalling and then reinstalling axlsx and rubyzip.

Axlsx hasn't been updated in 5 years.  Try using the caxlsx fork.

Ben, I tried dummying down rubyzip to v1.0.0, but when I tried executing my script I got another error:  "Could not find 'rubyzip' (>= 1.3.0, < 3.0.0) ..."  I don't seem to be able to get axlsx and rubyzip to work and play together.
